# hibernate template foreign key method to insert

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hbm

I am having two hbm files  `employee.hbm.xml`  and  `admin.hbm.xml`  and its corresponding entity classes.I did **Many to One mapping** when i try to insert the value the value is getting inserted but the update query is also executed.I am using hibernate template save method.Is there any method in hibernate template to do that

Comment: question is not too clear, please explain brief? and what exactly you want to achive? also what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: I have an empid in employee.hbm.xml which is going to act as a foreign key  in admin.hbm.xml.I used many to one mapping.My problem is when i'm executing the value is inserted in admin table  but it is asking me to update all the values in the employee table

Comment: object structure is not clear  but seems it against the software engineering paradigam, here is the things should be, correct me if i'm wrong .. you must have employee object and admin in that ... so it will be employee *----1admin mapping,  if you are inserting employee it will have admin in it, if you inserting admin, nothing have to do. ...... also please put your object structure and hbm file in question..